# ElasticSearch Rest API in JAVA

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to write a simple JAVA REST Client through which I want to PUT/GET  elasticsearch document information.
PUT is working fine, my json data got added into index.
But the problem is GET, Response Code is 200, but it is not returning any data.

Can anyone please help.

```
public static String httpGet(String resturl){
    String output = null; 
    try {

            URL url = new URL(resturl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));


            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(output);
            }

            conn.disconnect();

          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

          } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

          }

      return output;
}
```

I am calling as

RestClient.httpGet("http://localhost:9200/gabsindex/employee/_search")

Comment: Why would you do that? you know that there are multiple client libraries for elasticsearch in java, .net, js, python, and more.....

Answer (score 0):

You `println` call is currently commented out. If you uncomment it, you'll get the response from the server on one single line, something like

```
{"took":50,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":7056,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[...]}}
```

If you are trying to follow this approach educationally, this can be ok. Remember, nonetheless, that there are a number of libraries that can be used exactly for this use. You should check out the [clients page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/community/current/clients.html).